# IONIC 4 : getActiveIndex() is not working in ion-slides

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

Using IONIC 4 ion-slides, I am trying to get currently clicked silde index using getActiveIndex() as below which it is not working.

```
<ion-slides #testSlider (ionSlideTap)="getIndex()">
 <ion-slide>....</ion-slide>
</ion-slides>


@ViewChild('testSlider') slider: ElementRef;  // first way

getIndex() {
     this.slider.nativeElement.getActiveIndex();
}


@ViewChild('testSlider') slider: Slider; //second way

getIndex() {
     this.slider.getActiveIndex();
}
```

And the another way as below which is also not working:

```
<ion-slides #testSlider (ionSlideTap)="getIndex(testSlider)">
 <ion-slide>....</ion-slide>
</ion-slides>


getIndex(testSlider) {
     testSlider.getActiveIndex();
}
```

Can anyone please suggest me how can I get **active index** or **currently clicked slide index** in IONIC 4 ?

Comment: Hi @Darshana, did you manage to find a solution to this?

Comment: According to the documentation at https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/slides/, you should just be able to call this.slides.getActiveIndex(). This return an object that contains the index, amongst other info. I'm trying to extract the value now. Will report back if I manage to get it working

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, but managed to solve it as follows:

```
export class SomePage implements OnInit {
  ...
  currentIndex:Number = 0;
  ...

  getSlideIndex(){
   this.slides.getActiveIndex().then(
     (index)=>{
       this.currentIndex = index;
    });
  }
  ...
  this.getSlideIndex();
  console.log(this.currentIndex);
```

Note that although it seems to work, I suspect that because the value is changes inside  promise, it will only return the correct value if it has not recently changed. I thus intend to update this with a wait implemented to counter this.

Comment: Can you check if my solution (corrected one) is working for you?

Answer (score 3):

in template

```
<ion-slides pager="true" (ionSlideDidChange)="slideChanged($event)" #slides>
</ion-slides>
```

in component

```
import { IonSlides } from '@ionic/angular';

@ViewChild('slides', {static: true}) slides: IonSlides;

slideChanged(e: any) {
    this.slides.getActiveIndex().then((index: number) => {
        console.log(index);
    });
}
```

Comment: Best solution even! Thanks! :-)

Answer (score 3):

According to [the documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/slides), `getActiveIndex()` returns a `Promise<number>`.
So by using `ionSlideTap`:

```
<ion-slides (ionSlideTap)="onSlideTapped($event)">
    ...
</ion-slides>
```

I found two ways to do it:

- As [phunder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54403864/2668136) suggests, you can use `then()` to retrieve its value. I also did it with `async/await`:

  ```
  async onSlideTapped(event: any) {
      const index: number = await event.target.getActiveIndex();
      console.log(index);
  }
  ```
- Or you can use the `swiper` object:

  ```
  onSlideTapped(event: any) {
      console.log(event.target.swiper.clickedIndex);
  }
  ```

Therefore, you don't have to listen for every changes or to import the `IonSlides` in your component.

Answer (score 1):

UPDATED:

I think I made a few mistakes, here is working example (Ionic 3). Please make sure you are using $event.

Template file:

```
<ion-slides (ionSlideTap)="getIndex($event)">
 <ion-slide>1</ion-slide>
</ion-slides>
```

Now in TS file:

```
getIndex(event) {
  console.log(event.clickedIndex);
}
```

Try the above approach?

Here is working stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-ssvout

Comment: I have tried with above approach but that is also not working.

Comment: Good day @sergey, I have also tried this approach, but the value returned is "undefined"

Comment: @phunder hey I checked my answer and corrected it. Please see stackblitz

Answer (score 1):

for ionic 4

*.html

```
<ion-slides #slides (ionSlideDidChange)="slideChanged(slides)">
  ...
</ion-slides>
```

*. ts

```
 ...
 @ViewChild('slides', { static: false }) slides: IonSlides;
 ...
 slideChanged(slides: IonSlides) {
   slides.getActiveIndex().then((index: number) => {
    console.log(index);
    this.currentIndex = index;
   });
 }
```

Comment: Not Working. Please help me out with other solution

Comment: i see your post, maybe you forget declaration of  *slide* like
@ViewChild('slides', { static: false }) slides: Ion Slides;

Comment: It's not required bro

Answer (score 1):

1)Assign id to the respective  like #slides

```html
<div>
   <ion-slides #slide (ionSlideDidChange)="SlideChanges(slide)">

   </ion-slides>
</div>
```

2) import IonSlides in  your.ts page/component

> import { IonSlides } from '@ionic/angular';

3). Use method

```js
SlideChanges(slide: IonSlides) {
   slide.getActiveIndex().then((index: number) => {
    this.yourSlideIndex= index;
       alert(this.yourSlideIndex)
   });
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It's working...!

```js
// Typescript
import { IonSlides } from '@ionic/angular';
// in Component Class
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('contentSlider') contentSlider: IonSlides;
  constructor(){}
  ngOnInit() {}
  
  do_getActiveSlide(e: any) {
    this.contentSlider.getActiveIndex().then((index: number) => {
      console.log("Current active slide index", index);
    });
  }
}
```

```css
div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 5em;
  color: gold;
  background-color: #333;
  margin: 1.5em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="module" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@ionic/core/dist/ionic/ionic.esm.js"></script>
<script nomodule src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@ionic/core/dist/ionic/ionic.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@ionic/core/css/ionic.bundle.css"/>

<ion-slides pager="true" (ionSlideDidChange)="do_getActiveSlide($event)" #contentSlider>
  <ion-slide>
    <div>1</div>
  </ion-slide>
  <ion-slide>
    <div>2</div>
  </ion-slide>
  <ion-slide>
    <div>3</div>
  </ion-slide>
</ion-slides>
```